# SQLite: Subquery to group by max count

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite database of the following sample rows with columns of {id, temperatures, description, time_stamp:

```
1   45  Clear   2016-01-13 10:24:17
2   45  Clear   2016-01-13 10:24:41
3   45  Clear   2016-01-13 10:24:41
4   45  Rain    2016-01-13 10:24:41
5   46  Clear   2016-01-13 10:38:29
6   46  Clear   2016-01-13 10:38:53
7   46  Clear   2016-01-13 10:39:08
8   46  Clear   2016-01-13 10:39:08
```

I run this query on them to group them by a time interval and weather description:

```
SELECT AVG(current_temperatures) AS temp_avg,  
            CASE WHEN  strftime('%M',  time_stamp) < '30' 
            THEN strftime('%H', time_stamp)  
            ELSE strftime('%H', time_stamp, '+1 hours') END as hour, 
            current_weather_description, 
            count(*) as counter
            FROM weather_events
            GROUP BY strftime('%H',  time_stamp, '+30 minutes'), current_weather_description
            order by hour desc
```

With the following results {row_num, temp_avg, hour, current_weather_description, counter}:

```
"46.0"  "11"    "Clear" "4"
"45.0"  "10"    "Clear" "3"
"45.0"  "10"    "Rain"  "1"
```

My problem is how do I sub query each individual hour and group by the max counter. So ultimately I want to get the result:

```
"46.0"  "11"    "Clear" "4"
"45.0"  "10"    "Clear" "3"
```

I'm new to SQL and SQLite. All of the data comes from the same table.
Also since the queried temperatures are averages, how does it choose the rest of the columns I ask it to select? For example if you select the time_stamp as well you'll see that it's a particular time_stamp from the database. Does it randomly choose which columns to select?

Answer (score 0):

You get right output by your sql query. You've grouped rows by `half hour time intervals` and `weather description`. You have two various weathers for `10:00 time interval`: "Clear" and "Rain" and one weather for `10:30 time interval`: "Clear" . If you will remove weather_description column from `GROUP BY` clause you will get only two rows.

Solution with `common table expressions` to show only weather description that happens most often in the time interval.

```
;WITH temp_data AS(
    SELECT AVG(current_temperatures) AS temp_avg,  
            CASE WHEN  strftime('%M',  time_stamp) < '30' 
            THEN strftime('%H', time_stamp)  
            ELSE strftime('%H', time_stamp, '+1 hours') END as hour, 
            current_weather_description,
            count(*) as counter
    FROM weather_events
    GROUP BY strftime('%H',  time_stamp, '+30 minutes'),
             current_weather_description
)

SELECT T1.* FROM temp_data AS T1
WHERE T1.counter = (SELECT MAX(counter) FROM temp_data AS T2
                    WHERE T2.hour = T1.hour)
```

Comment: When I do that it then outputs "Rain" as the description, which I don't want because it was mostly clear for that time interval

Comment: So this means that you want to show weather description that happens often than others, right?

Comment: any ideas? @fabulaspb

Comment: @M.Smith why you don't like solution with CTE?

Comment: so sorry, didn't see that change, will check it out and get back to you